# Expose NativeActivity Variables to Workflow Designer

Tags: .net, workflow, workflow-foundation-4, workflow-activity

I've got a `NativeActivity` which contains an `Activity` body. The purpose of this activity is to expose a resource for the duration of the child activity as a `Variable`. The problem I've encountered is it appears the `Variable` cannot be used outside the activity. I'll use `StreamReader` as an example resource.

ResourceActivity.cs:

```
[Designer(typeof(ResourceActivityDesigner))]
public sealed class ResourceActivity : NativeActivity
{
    [RequiredArgument]
    public InArgument<string> Path { get; set; }

    [Browsable(false), EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
    public Activity Body { get; set; }

    [Browsable(false), EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
    public Variable<StreamReader> Resource { get; set; }

    public ResourceActivity()
    {
        this.Resource = new Variable<StreamReader>
        {
            Default = null,
            Name = "reader"
        };
    }

    protected override void CacheMetadata(NativeActivityMetadata metadata)
    {
        if (this.Path != null) metadata.AddArgument(this.Path);
        if (this.Body != null) metadata.AddChild(this.Body);
        if (this.Resource != null) metadata.AddVariable(this.Resource);
    }

    protected override void Execute(NativeActivityContext context)
    {
        this.Resource.Set(context, new StreamReader(this.Path.Get(context)));
        context.ScheduleActivity(this.Body, new completionCallback(Done), new FaultCallback(Faulted));
    }

    private void Done(NativeActivityContext context, ActivityInstance instance)
    {
        var reader = this.Reader.Get(context);
        if (reader != null) reader.Dispose();
    }

    private void Faulted(NativeActivityFaultContext context, Exception ex, ActivityInstance instance)
    {
        var reader = this.Reader.Get(context);
        if (reader != null) reader.Dispose();
    }
}
```

I cannot view "Resource" or "reader" in the Variables list in the Workflow Designer. Am I missing something in `CacheMetadata`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears the answer was adding an `Collection<Variable>` to the class. `CacheMetadata` was unnecessary.

```
[Browsable(false), EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
public Collection<Variable> Variables { get; private set; }

public ResourceActivity()
{
    this.Resource = new Variable<StreamReader> { Default = null, Name = "reader" };
    this.Variables = new Collection<Variable>(new [] { this.Resource });
}
```

**EDIT:** Nope, now an error occurs which states the Variable is defined multiple times. If I leave out adding the resource to the variables collection it just doesn't show up...

**EDIT #2:** I submitted this as a bug on Microsoft Connect and was told this is a known bug, [but it is not targetted for a fix in VS 2010. It has been postponed.](https://connect.microsoft.com/wf/feedback/details/566239/variables-defined-in-custom-activities-do-not-show-up-in-designer?wa=wsignin1.0)

Comment: Your first error is because the Variables are being serialized to xaml so when it gets deserialized, your constructor first adds the variable then the deserialized one gets added to the collection, causing that error.  Move that code into IActivityTemplateFactory.Create and you won't have that error.  The bug you reported seems to be a different one, where an Activity can't create and expose variables for its children while also being able to access them.  Some kind of scope BS.  Having the same issue.  Ever find a workaround?

Comment: btw, I'm actually thinking of creating a dummy child activity whose sole purpose is to update the Variable.  Effing.  Ridiculous.

Comment: @Will: we went and restructured that application due to massive frustration with WF and a lack of any coherent documentation of anything beyond the trivial. MS's support for WF is so abhorrent we basically canned that part of the app due to a lack of sufficient workarounds. If you add your bit about serialization/deserialization as an answer I'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: Nah, that's k.  I'm not so down on WF4 as you apparently are.  Been able to do some real complex and impressive stuff.  But it *is* a new product, and as such there isn't lots of information about it.  I do agree they could stand to add more clarity to the MSDN docs... On many subjects.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define your Body as type ActivityAction instead of Activity if you want to share a variable between the activity itself and the children. See [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/mwinkle/swiss-cheese-and-wf4-or-an-introduction-to-activityaction) blog post by Matt Winkler.